# javascript url redirect with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, redirect

I would like to redirect when the URL doesn't match a certain regex.

A client of ours signed a contract with a very shady SEO company - ReachLocal. They send their adwords campaign to our site. Using js to change some key-information like phone-numbers, mailto-info, analytics onclick pushes,...

Because our site is shown in another url, it must be possible to have a script in source that examines url and redirects when on other domain.

This is what I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.match(/rtrk\.be/);) {        => the use domain rtrk.be
window.location.href = 'http://example.com'; 
}
</script>
```

I'm not really into js so help is much appreciated.

Comment: typo in you'r `if`, dont put a semicolon there `if (url.match(/rtrk\.be/))`

Comment: Learn to use **developer console**. It will log your errors

Comment: You should use the ! operator. Also @Nano I think that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @CyberFox I don't think the typo is worth an answer :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have semicolon astray.

Any reason you don't use "contains()"? Anyways this is my answer.

```
if(location.href.contains("rtrk.be")==false)
    location.href = "punk.com";
```

Comment: Works like a charm locally, but not to redirect from SearchLocal url. If you want to see what I'm about: type 'bermax' in google click on advertisement for 'bermaxbvba.be'.

Comment: I entered rtrk.be and i was redirected to "https://www.reachlocal.com/us/en/rtrk.be". I can see there is a problem with this rule of "contains()". But looking further into the location object i found that there is a property called "host" which is more safe.

Comment: if(location.host!=="rtrk.be")
    location.href = "punk.com";

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use test:

```
if (!/rtrk\.be/.test(url)) {        => the use domain rtrk.be
    window.location.href = 'http://example.com'; 
}
```

Your mistakes:

- remove ';' from if statement
- your regex is checking if url is matching rtrk.be, but you want to navigate when url does not match it, so you are missing negation (in regex or in if statement)